# Why use Gradle instead of Ant or Maven?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build-process, gradle

What does another build tool targeted at Java really get me?

If you use Gradle over another tool, why?

Comment: Google jumped in with Gradle for android sdk. https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325236644.  Intellij has now added support for gradle. That puts gradle into main stream (not just toy projects)

Comment: Spring artifacts are now created by Gradle too, I think Hibernate is the same.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

I don't use [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) in anger myself (just a toy project so far) *[author means they have used Gradle on only a toy project so far, not that Gradle is a toy project - see comments]*, but I'd say that the reasons one would consider using it would be because of the frustrations of Ant and Maven.

In my experience Ant is often write-only (yes I know it is possible to write [beautifully modular, elegant build](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/17/ant_bestpractices.Html)s, but the fact is most people don't). For any non-trivial projects it becomes mind-bending, and takes great care to ensure that complex builds are truly portable. Its imperative nature can lead to replication of configuration between builds (though macros can help here).

Maven takes the opposite approach and expects you to completely integrate with the Maven lifecycle. Experienced Ant users find this particularly jarring as Maven removes many of the freedoms you have in Ant. For example there's a [Sonatype blog](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/05/were-used-to-the-axe-grinding/) that enumerates many of the Maven criticisms and their responses.

The Maven plugin mechanism allows for very powerful build configurations, and the inheritance model means you can define a small set of parent POMs encapsulating your build configurations for the whole enterprise and individual projects can inherit those configurations, leaving them lightweight. Maven configuration is very verbose (though Maven 3 promises to address this), and if you want to do anything that is "not the Maven way" you have to write a plugin or use the hacky Ant integration. Note I happen to like writing Maven plugins but appreciate that many will object to the effort involved.

Gradle promises to hit the sweet spot between Ant and Maven. It uses [Ivy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy)'s approach for dependency resolution. It allows for convention over configuration but also includes Ant tasks as first class citizens. It also wisely allows you to use existing Maven/Ivy repositories.

So if you've hit and got stuck with any of the Ant/Maven pain points, it is probably worth trying Gradle out, though in my opinion it remains to be seen if you wouldn't just be trading known problems for unknown ones. The proof of the pudding is in the eating though so I would reserve judgment until the product is a little more mature and others have ironed out any kinks (they call it bleeding edge for a reason). I'll still be using it in my toy projects though, It's always good to be aware of the options.

Comment: @Tom I was not saying that Gradle is a toy project, but that I have only used it on a toy project so far. Sorry you felt misled

Comment: Sleer - despite the age, I edited the post to clarify inline what is clarified in the comments - the misunderstanding immediately colors the post as anti-Gradle.  If someone researching Gradle (like myself) initially misunderstands that opening sentence (like I did), they might not read much further or read the clarifying comment (like I almost did). Please revert/edit my change if you disagree/dislike it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did not get the impression @RichSeller meant Gradle was for toy projects at all (even before reading the part in square brackets).

Comment: When I read "only a toy project so far", I instantly got the impression that the author was referring to Gradle itself being a toy project, especially after the confusing "I don't use Gradle in anger myself". This suggests that the author does use Gradle when not in anger. I suggest just rewriting the first whole sentence.

Answer (score 79):

Gradle can be used for many purposes - it's a much better Swiss army knife than Ant - but it's specifically focused on multi-project builds.

First of all, Gradle is a dependency programming tool which also means it's a programming tool. With Gradle you can execute any random task in your setup and Gradle will make sure all declared dependecies are properly and timely executed. Your code can be spread across many directories in any kind of layout (tree, flat, scattered, ...).

Gradle has two distinct phases: evaluation and execution. Basically, during evaluation Gradle will look for and evaluate build scripts in the directories it is supposed to look. During execution Gradle will execute tasks which have been loaded during evaluation taking into account task inter-dependencies.

On top of these dependency programming features Gradle adds project and JAR dependency features by intergration with Apache Ivy. As you know Ivy is a much more powerful and much less opinionated dependency management tool than say Maven.

Gradle detects dependencies between projects and between projects and JARs. Gradle works with Maven repositories (download and upload) like the iBiblio one or your own repositories but also supports and other kind of repository infrastructure you might have.

In multi-project builds Gradle is both adaptable and adapts to the build's structure and architecture. You don't have to adapt your structure or architecture to your build tool as would be required with Maven.

Gradle tries very hard not to get in your way, an effort Maven almost never makes. Convention is good yet so is flexibility. Gradle gives you many more features than Maven does but most importantly in many cases Gradle will offer you a painless transition path away from Maven.

Answer (score 64):

This may be a bit controversial, but Gradle doesn't hide the fact that it's a fully-fledged programming language.

Ant + ant-contrib is essentially a turing complete programming language that no one really wants to program in.

Maven tries to take the opposite approach of trying to be completely declarative and forcing you to write and compile a plugin if you need logic.  It also imposes a project model that is completely inflexible.  Gradle combines the best of all these tools:

- It follows convention-over-configuration (ala Maven) but only to the extent you want it
- It lets you write flexible custom tasks like in Ant
- It provides multi-module project support that is superior to both Ant and Maven
- It has a DSL that makes the 80% things easy and the 20% things possible (unlike other build tools that make the 80% easy, 10% possible and 10% effectively impossible).

Gradle is the most configurable and flexible build tool I have yet to use.  It requires some investment up front to learn the DSL and concepts like configurations but if you need a no-nonsense and completely configurable JVM build tool it's hard to beat.

Answer (score 49):

Gradle nicely combines both Ant and Maven, taking the best from both frameworks. Flexibility from Ant and convention over configuration, dependency management and plugins from Maven.

So if you want to have a standard java build, like in maven, but test task has to do some custom step it could look like below.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin:'java'
task test{
  doFirst{
    ant.copy(toDir:'build/test-classes'){fileset dir:'src/test/extra-resources'}
  }
  doLast{
    ...
  }
}
```

On top of that it uses groovy syntax which gives much more expression power then ant/maven's xml.

It is a superset of Ant - you can use all Ant tasks in gradle with nicer, groovy-like syntax, ie.

```
ant.copy(file:'a.txt', toDir:"xyz")
```

or

```
ant.with{
  delete "x.txt"
  mkdir "abc"
  copy file:"a.txt", toDir: "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 35):

We use Gradle and chose it over Maven and Ant. Ant gave us total flexibility, and Ivy gives better dependency management than Maven, but there isn't great support for multi-project builds. You end up doing a lot of coding to support multi-project builds. Also having some build-by-convention is nice and makes build scripts more concise. With Maven, it takes build by convention too far, and customizing your build process becomes a hack. Also, Maven promotes every project publishing an artifact. Sometimes you have a project split up into subprojects but you want all of the subprojects to be built and versioned together. Not really something Maven is designed for.

With Gradle you can have the flexibility of Ant and build by convention of Maven. For example, it is trivial to extend the conventional build lifecycle with your own task. And you aren't forced to use a convention if you don't want to. Groovy is much nicer to code than XML. In Gradle, you can define dependencies between projects on the local file system without the need to publish artifacts for each to a repository. Finally, Gradle uses Ivy, so it has excellent dependency management. The only real downside for me thus far is the lack of mature Eclipse integration, but the options for Maven aren't really much better.

Comment: Personally, I think the Eclipse integration is just fine.  Installing it into Juno is fairly simple.

Comment: 2 years after the author wrote this answer though!

Answer (score 21):

This isn't *my* answer, but it definitely resonates with me.  It's from [ThoughtWorks' Technology Radar from October 2012](http://www.thoughtworks.com/articles/technology-radar-october-2012):

> Two things have caused fatigue with XML-based build tools like Ant and
>   Maven: too many angry pointy braces and the coarseness of plug-in
>   architectures. While syntax issues can be dealt with through
>   generation, plug-in architectures severely limit the ability for build
>   tools to grow gracefully as projects become more complex. We have come
>   to feel that plug-ins are the wrong level of abstraction, and prefer
>   language-based tools like Gradle and Rake instead, because they offer
>   finer-grained abstractions and more flexibility long term.

Answer (score 16):

Gradle put the fun back into building/assembling software. I used ant to build software my entire career and I have always considered the actual "buildit" part of the dev work being a necessary evil. A few months back our company grew tired of not using a binary repo (aka checking in jars into the vcs) and I was given the task to investigate this. Started with ivy since it could be bolted on top of ant, didn't have much luck getting my built artifacts published like I wanted. I went for maven and hacked away with xml, worked splendid for some simple helper libs but I ran into serious problems trying to bundle applications ready for deploy. Hassled quite a while googling plugins and reading forums and wound up downloading trillions of support jars for various plugins which I had a hard time using. Finally I went for gradle (getting quite bitter at this point, and annoyed that "It shouldn't be THIS hard!")

But from day one my mood started to improve. I was getting somewhere. Took me like two hours to migrate my first ant module and the build file was basically nothing. Easily fitted one screen. The big "wow" was: build *scripts* in xml, how stupid is that? the fact that declaring one dependency takes ONE row is very appealing to me -> you can easily see all dependencies for a certain project on one page. From then on I been on a constant roll, for every problem I faced so far there is a simple and elegant solution. I think these are the reasons:

- groovy is very intuitive for java developers

  documentation is great to awesome

  the flexibility is endless

Now I spend my days trying to think up new features to add to our build process. How sick is that?

Comment: +1 for "build *scripts* in xml, how stupid is that?"  In 2000, XML was considered the coolest thing ever, so in all fairness, it seemed more trendy than stupid at the time.  XML-based programming languages are basically lisps because they have the open/close delimiters for every command.  But they are super-verbose versions of lisp where 4 characters of code become 40 characters.  It's one way of learning how to type, but not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 8):

It's also much easier to manage native builds.  Ant and Maven are effectively Java-only. Some plugins exist for Maven that try to handle some native projects, but they don't do an effective job.  Ant tasks can be written that compile native projects, but they are too complex and awkward.

We do Java with JNI and lots of other native bits.  Gradle simplified our Ant mess considerably.  When we started to introduce dependency management to the native projects it was messy.  We got Maven to do it, but the equivalent Gradle code was a tiny fraction of what was needed in Maven, and people could read it and understand it without becoming Maven gurus.

Answer (score 3):

I agree partly with Ed Staub. Gradle definitely is more powerful compared to maven and provides more flexibility long term.

After performing an evaluation to move from maven to gradle, we decided to stick to maven itself for two issues
we encountered with gradle ( speed is slower than maven, proxy was not working ) .

Comment: I had proxy issues with v1.2 but since then I think it has been working. So much so, ctnlm or app like that is a solution for maven to solve NTLM proxy issues. 
Gradle has this support out of the box. although this is so trivial I wonder why Maven never had this support out of the box for NTLM auth based proxies.