# What is difference between ant, maven, gradle build tool

Tags: eclipse, maven, netbeans, ant

Eclipse uses Maven and Netbeans ANT as build tool. Here is a confusion which IDE should I use for developing projects. What are the advantages and disadvantages of these build tools.

Can anyone?

Comment: This question is _"primarily opinion-based"_, and is therefore off topic for SO. And regardless of that, the scope of your question is far too broad. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further information. (And your claim that Netbeans uses "ANT as build tool" is just wrong; with NetBeans you are free to use Ant or Maven or Gradle, and there are project creation wizards that support the use of each approach.)

Comment: "Eclipse uses Maven and Netbeans ANT as build tool" - that is wrong. see also Sambit's answer.

Answer (score 2):

IDEs like Eclipse, Intellij Idea and Netbeans provides facilities to create a java project with build tool like Maven, Gradle or Ant. It is upto the developer to make selection from UI of the IDEs. It is also possible to create a project without using any build tools.

To know the various differences in Ant, Maven and Gradle, refer below the following links.

https://medium.com/@kapil.sharma91812/few-points-on-java-build-tools-ant-vs-maven-vs-gradle-e149a43325b8

https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle

[Why use Gradle instead of Ant or Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163173/why-use-gradle-instead-of-ant-or-maven)